# Breaking SHA1 using a length extension attack

Tags: hash, sha1

I'm implementing this flaw of SHA1:

https://blog.whitehatsec.com/hash-length-extension-attacks/

I need to SHA1 a chunk of data, then using the resulting hash as the starting vector, I will SHA1 a second chunk of data.

Like:

```
firstHash = SHA1(fisrtchunk)
setSHA1StartingVector(firstHash)
secondHash = SHA1(secondchunk)
```

#### Do you any library who let you apply SHA1 using a custom starting vector?

Comment: No, I don't do such a library.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. search for shaext python module.